# Stored Procedure results into a file only if not null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

I am trying to execute Stored Procedure on a regular basis using a SQL Job and store the results of this into a .txt file in a folder location.

I have used the BCP command which is like:

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(1000)
SET @command = 'BCP "Exec [DatabaseName].[dbo].[StoredProcedureName] " queryout "D:\In\ErrorDetails'+ '.txt" -c -T -t -k'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @command
```

I need this to execute only if results of SP are not null.

Comment: Use EXISTS  to see if it returns NULL before calling the proc.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use temp table to store data generated by SP, if there are any rows - write it to file

```
USE tempdb

IF OBJECT_ID(N'#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
END

SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=HOME\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC Test.dbo.StoredProcedureName');

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #MyTempTable) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @command VARCHAR(1000) 
    SET @command = 'BCP "USE tempdb SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable " queryout "D:\In\ErrorDetails'+ '.txt" -c -T -t -k' 
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @command
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i get the below error:
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".

Comment: I have no idea about the OLE DB provider. I guess i need to replace SQLNCLl11 with my OLE DB provider name. But where do i get that?

Comment: I've got `Server=HOME\SQLEXPRESS` what is yours? How do you re-write this part? This problem usually occurs when provider cannot find server. If it is on your local machine you can use `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`. Maybe you got some other instance name.

Comment: SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
This is the error. I have now given the correct Server name

Comment: Nope, "SQLNCLI11" is the default Linked Server Provider which is used, and i tried ".\" and "MyServerName\SQLEXPRESS".
It was of no use.

Comment: Is there any alternative to SELECT into #MyTempTable apart from OPENROWSET functionality?

Comment: Another way is to create temp table manually with all columns definition. Here is a nice sample to avoid OPENROWSET http://stackoverflow.com/a/21582634/2893376 and create temp table automatically.

Comment: I tried the second option:
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#MyTempTable'.
Inside the BCP, the select query does not work!

Comment: add `USE tempdb ` before `SELECT * FROM...` all `#table_name' tables are stored in `tempdb`.